# Can you use lincom with interaction models coded with ## in Stata?

Tags: stata

I am trying to use lincom to sum regression coefficients in a Stata model that codes interaction using ##. Exposure and bmi are continuous variables. Sex is binary.

```
regr bmi c.exposure##sex covar1 covar2 covar3 i.covar4 i.covar5
lincom chemical + chemical#sex
```

The regression works just fine, but lincom gives the following error:

> exposure##sex invalid name

Alternatively, if I code the second line as

```
lincom chemical + c.chemical##sex
```

then I get

> invalid matrix stripe;
>   c.l10_mep_i_sg2_pg##sex

Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible with # interaction coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the `, coeflegend` option at the end of your regression command. This will allow you to see what Stata calls each coefficient.

Here's a *reproducible* example:

```
sysuse auto
reg price i.foreign##c.mpg, coeflegend
lincom 1.foreign+ 1.foreign#c.mpg*25
```

Alternatively, this sort of thing can usually be done much more easily with `margins`:

```
margins, dydx(foreign) at(mpg=25)
```

Both of these give you the marginal effect of foreign origin on price when miles per gallon is 25.